# struct as wrapper for value types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wrapper

I have just begun with C#. I noticed that all the value types are wrapped into respective `struct`s. I did look up for the reason behind it, couldn't find much though(maybe I didn't search properly). I just wanted to ask - what is the reason that value types are wrapped as `struct`s in C# as opposed to wrapper classes in Java?

EDIT:

When I hover onto `int`, I guess it shows me this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.71%29 . From the comments, I understand that I might be understanding something wrong here. If `int` isn't wrapped into that `struct`, then why does it show information about that?

Comment: What do you mean "value types are wrapped into respective structs"?

Comment: "value type" and "struct" are synonymous...

Comment: @KirkWoll when I type `int` in Visual Studio and hover over it, it shows something like `struct System.Int32`.(maybe wrong, but I'm sure I did see a `struct` there).

Comment: @KazekageGaara that isn't *wrapped*, though; `int` ***is*** `System.Int32` - they are identical, one-and-the-same, aliases

Comment: I guess when I hover `int` it shows up this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.71%29.

Comment: Do you mean why are types with value semantics implemented as structs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I *believe* this is just a bit of confusion over what the IDE is telling you. Firstly, unlike Java there is **absolutely no difference** between `int` and `Int32`. It **isn't** the "primitive" and "boxed" versions of the same thing; simply, `int` is the c# name for convenience; the full name (since the CLI supports other languages etc) is `global::System.Int32`; but that is **just** an alias; they are identical and interchangeable.

Secondly, `struct` is a synonym for "value-type"; again, same meaning (mostly).

There is no wrapping here; when the IDE talks about "struct Int32" it is also talking about "primitive int". They are the same. The main point is: `int` is treated as a value not a reference, which means it is a "struct"; that is *all* that is trying to tell you, i.e. "not a reference".

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies a lot. :-)